# How to compile and run a infinite loop .c program in a Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

System: VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04

This question sounds like stupid, but I have stuck at this problem for hours. (Purely new to Makefile)

Here is the description:

The program (`sh.c`)simulates a shell, which is a infinite loop. User can exit if they enter builtin command `exit`, like below:

```
> gcc -o sh sh.c
> ./sh
>>> $ (user can enter command)
        ...
        ...
>>> $ exit
Goodbye!
> (back to bash)
```

The question is if I want to place `gcc -o sh sh.c` and `./sh` into Makefile and enter `make` to run, bash will stuck like this:

```
> make
gcc sh.c -o sh
./sh

(stucking...)
```

and I cannot type commands also cannot exit by `Ctrl + C`.

I believe the problem is in the Makefile, because program can run smoothly if I don't use Makefile, and below is my Makefile:

```
all: compile run

.PHONY: all clean

CC := gcc

FLAG := -Wall
SRC := sh.c
EXE := sh

compile: $(SRC)
    $(CC) -o $(EXE) $(SRC)

run:
    ./$(EXE)

clean:
    rm -rf $(EXE)
```

I wonder what is the problem in the Makefile, thanks in advance!

Comment: So use a makefile to manage *builds* of your program, which is what `make` is designed for, and run the resulting program directly, as (presumably) it's intended to be run.

Comment: I tried your makefile and it worked fine.

Comment: You should make `compile` depend on `$(EXE)`, not `$(SRC)`, so it doesn't recompile when the source hasn't changed.

Comment: @Barmar Still got the same behavior, but I decide to just let Makefile compile for `sh.c`, and enter `./sh` manually, thanks for advide anyway!

Comment: I didn't mean that would fix the problem. I can't reproduce your problem with your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this weird behavior must be related to your implementation of `sh.c`.  Using a normal shell, for example, works fine for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
run: ; /bin/sh
```

Now I can run `make` and it starts a shell and I can type stuff into it and it works:

```
$ make
/bin/sh
$ echo hi
hi
$ exit
```

But, as John says, `make` is not intended to allow you to run interactive programs.  It's intended to allow you to build programs and run other commands non-interactively.  If you use `make -j` for example (parallel builds) only one rule can get access to `stdin` at a time and there's no way to know which one it will be.  Etc.

You should keep the `compile` rule (although it should be written differently: it's always wrong for a make recipe to build a different file than the name of the target) but throw away the `run` rule, and just run the command from your shell prompt after `make` is done.

```
all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(SRC)
        $(CC) -o $(EXE) $(SRC)
```

Comment: So, does it mean conventionally (for most of the time) Makefile is just for bundling (linking) multiple files into one executable file, and we still need to type another run command for example `./sh`? (i.e. type `make` and `./xxx` 2 commands rather than only typing `make` and expect program(s) to run)

Comment: I mean just as above: make is best for running _non-interactive_ programs, not _interactive_ programs.  If, for example, after building your program you had a test suite that would run your program in various ways to test it and make sure it worked, _non-interactively_, then it would be useful to create a `test` or similar target in your makefile that invoked that test suite.

Comment: I know your point, thanks!